# Vue3 Component Prop A or B, not both, not neither

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a component that displays text and either an image or a colored circle like so:

[image: Two identical rectangle shaped components, where one contains an image in a circle and some text and the other contains just a colored circle and some text]

Currently the component's props look like this:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    // Props
    interface Props {
        title: string 
        imagePath?: string   # String path to an image asset
        color?: `#${string}` # String starting with a Hash, such as #16A2B0
    }
    const props = defineProps<Props>()

[...]

</script>
```

When using the component with a color, it would look like this:

```
<MyComponent color="#DEDEDE"/>
```

When using the component with a image path, it would look like this:

```
<MyComponent image-path="src/assets/image.png" />
```

Right now, I have it so that both the `color` prop and the `imagePath` prop are optional, because there is never a case where you would need both. However, this allows the user to provide none as well, which is also undesired.

**Is there a way using Vue 3 Composition API in Typescript I can specify that for this component, you need EITHER a `color` prop OR an `imagePath` prop and you don't need both, only one or the other, and you can't have neither?**

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs provides a [custom validator](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation) for each prop. But unfortunately, it lacks the capability to access other props within a validator. You can see [the issue here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3495).

So I'm afraid that, there is no straight way to solve your problem. But there are two workarounds that you can choose:

1. Create a watcher to watch your props and throw a warning if the condition is not met

```js
watch(
  props,
  () => {
    if (!props.imagePath && !props.color) {
      console.warn('Required at least imagePath or color as the props')
    }
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
```

2. Pass your props as a single object then you can validate the whole props at one validator

```js
interface Props {
  title: string
  imagePath?: string
  color?: `#${string}`
}
defineProps({
  props: {
    type: Object as PropType<Props>,
    required: true,
    validator: (propsValue: Props) => {
      if (!propsValue.imagePath && !propsValue.color) {
        console.warn('Required at least imagePath or color as the props')
      }
      return false
    },
  },
})
```